# Коллизия обьедков плохо работает

Tags: python, pygame

коллизия у красного и зелёного квадрата работает только слева и снизу. Помогите пжлст

```
import pygame 
import time 
 
pygame.init() 
 
size = (700, 500) 
win = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
 
maze = [ 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
] 
 
maze_width = len(maze[0]) 
maze_height = len(maze) 
cell_size = 50 
 
player_x = cell_size 
player_y = cell_size 
player_size = 10 
 
running = True 
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
 
while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False 
 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x - player_size) // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_x -= player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_x += player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]: 
        if maze[(player_y - player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_y -= player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
        if maze[(player_y + player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_y += player_size 
 
    if pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size).colliderect( 
            pygame.Rect(0, 0, maze_width * cell_size, maze_height * cell_size)): 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 2: 
            print("уровень проиден") 
            time.sleep(3) 
 
            player_x = cell_size 
            player_y = cell_size 

    if pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size).colliderect( 
            pygame.Rect(0, 0, maze_width * cell_size, maze_height * cell_size)): 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 3:
            print("ШЫШ тебе а не побыду!")
 
    win.fill((255, 255, 255)) 
    for i in range(maze_height): 
        for j in range(maze_width): 
            if maze[i][j] == 1: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
            if maze[i][j] == 2: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
            if maze[i][j] == 3: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
 
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size)) 
    pygame.display.update() 
 
    clock.tick(10) 
 
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Да, с обьедками всегда так!

Comment: по факту, ведь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не самое хорошее решение проблемы, но если не переделывать половину кода, то как по другому не знаю.

```
import pygame 
import time 
 
pygame.init() 
 
size = (700, 500) 
win = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
 
maze = [ 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
] 
 
maze_width = len(maze[0]) 
maze_height = len(maze) 
cell_size = 50 
 
player_x = cell_size 
player_y = cell_size 
player_size = 10 
is_win = False

running = True 
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False 
    
    if is_win:
        time.sleep(3) 
        player_x = cell_size 
        player_y = cell_size
        is_win = False
        print("уровень проиден")

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x - player_size) // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_x -= player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        if maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_x += player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]: 
        if maze[(player_y - player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_y -= player_size 
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
        if maze[(player_y + player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 0: 
            player_y += player_size 
 
    if pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size).colliderect( 
            pygame.Rect(0, 0, maze_width * cell_size, maze_height * cell_size)): 
        if any([maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 2,
        maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x - player_size) // cell_size] == 2,
        maze[(player_y + player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 2,
        maze[(player_y - player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 2]):
            is_win = True

    if pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size).colliderect( 
            pygame.Rect(0, 0, maze_width * cell_size, maze_height * cell_size)): 
        if any([maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x + player_size) // cell_size] == 3,
        maze[player_y // cell_size][(player_x - player_size) // cell_size] == 3,
        maze[(player_y + player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 3,
        maze[(player_y - player_size) // cell_size][player_x // cell_size] == 3]):
            print("ШЫШ тебе а не побыду!")
 
    win.fill((255, 255, 255)) 
    for i in range(maze_height): 
        for j in range(maze_width): 
            if maze[i][j] == 1: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
            if maze[i][j] == 2: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
            if maze[i][j] == 3: 
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (j * cell_size, i * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)) 
 
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size)) 
    pygame.display.update() 
 
    clock.tick(10) 
 
pygame.quit()
```

Проблема была в том, что вы проверяли наличие красного или зелёного квадрата только справа, а нужно было со всех четырёх сторон, поэтому я добавил по три условия к обоим проверкам. Также я немного изменил эффект от прикосновения к квадрату, теперь игра перезапускается после отрисовки игрока, а до этого игрок застывал на расстоянии от квадрата.